# javascript looping through array displaying sub fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop and get the name of the places in the array below.

```
{
   "id":"100",
   "name":"the name",
   "places":[
      {
         "id":"23",
         "name":"first place",
         "startDate":"2015-01-30 15:01:00",
         "endDate":"2015-01-30 17:01:00"
      },

      {
         "id":"54",
         "name":"second place",
         "startDate":"2015-01-31 17:01:00",
         "endDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00"

      },
      {
         "id":"400",
         "name":"third place",
         "startDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00",
         "endDate":"2015-02-05 17:01:00"

      }

   ]

}
```

So this is what I've done:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainData.length; i++) {

     var obj = mainData.places[i];

     console.log(obj.places[i].name);
}
```

The code above is showing undefined so I have something wrong in the code.

How can I get console.log to display all the places names?

Comment: You're looping through `mainData` but using the index on `mainData.places`, and then try to log `mainData.places[i].places[i].name`.

Comment: `console.log(obj.name);` obj is the reference of the array element(object)

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < mainData.places.length; i++)` then `console.log(obj.name);`. Have you tried that?

Comment: `console.log(obj.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at Nina Scholz's answer as that really *helps* you understand your errors.

This is another approach (using `map`)

```js
var arr = {
    "id":"100",
        "name":"the name",
        "places":[
    {
        "id":"23",
        "name":"first place",
        "startDate":"2015-01-30 15:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-01-30 17:01:00"
    },

    {
        "id":"54",
        "name":"second place",
        "startDate":"2015-01-31 17:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00"

    },
    {
        "id":"400",
        "name":"third place",
        "startDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-02-05 17:01:00"

    }

]

}

var places = arr.places.map(function(e){
    return e.name;
});

console.log(places)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the length of `places` and the the right access to `name` via `obj`.

```js
var mainData = { "id": "100", "name": "the name", "places": [{ "id": "23", "name": "first place", "startDate": "2015-01-30 15:01:00", "endDate": "2015-01-30 17:01:00" }, { "id": "54", "name": "second place", "startDate": "2015-01-31 17:01:00", "endDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00" }, { "id": "400", "name": "third place", "startDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00", "endDate": "2015-02-05 17:01:00" }] },
    obj;

for (var i = 0; i < mainData.places.length; i++) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^
     obj = mainData.places[i];
     console.log(obj.name);
     //          ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `obj` is the reference to the inner object so get name property fro it. Although you need to check the length of `palces` property(which holds the array).

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainData.palces.length; i++) {
    //----------------------^^^^^^^^-------------
    var obj = mainData.places[i];
    console.log(obj.name);
    //------------^^^^^^^^--------
}
```

```js
var mainData = {
  "id": "100",
  "name": "the name",
  "places": [{
    "id": "23",
    "name": "first place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-30 15:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-01-30 17:01:00"
  }, {
    "id": "54",
    "name": "second place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-31 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00"

  }, {
    "id": "400",
    "name": "third place",
    "startDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-05 17:01:00"

  }]
};
for (var i = 0; i < mainData.places.length; i++) {
  var obj = mainData.places[i];
  console.log(obj.name);
  //------------^^^^^^^^--------
}
```

---

You can make it more simple using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method for iterating over array element.

```
mainData.places.forEach(function(v){
    console.log(v.name);
})
```

```js
var mainData = {
  "id": "100",
  "name": "the name",
  "places": [{
    "id": "23",
    "name": "first place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-30 15:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-01-30 17:01:00"
  }, {
    "id": "54",
    "name": "second place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-31 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00"

  }, {
    "id": "400",
    "name": "third place",
    "startDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-05 17:01:00"

  }]
};


 mainData.places.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v.name);
})
```

---

If you want to get names as an array use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method.

```
var res = mainData.places.map(function(v){
    return v.name;
})
```

```js
var mainData = {
  "id": "100",
  "name": "the name",
  "places": [{
    "id": "23",
    "name": "first place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-30 15:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-01-30 17:01:00"
  }, {
    "id": "54",
    "name": "second place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-31 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00"

  }, {
    "id": "400",
    "name": "third place",
    "startDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-05 17:01:00"

  }]
};


var res = mainData.places.map(function(v) {
  return v.name;
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: if `mainData` is the root object shown, this will not work - you need to loop over `mainData.places`

Comment: And you're making the same mistale as the OP and counting `mainData.length` then using the index in `maindata.places[i]`